# Pytesseract output into a list then split and getting error

Tags: python-tesseract

I'm trying to have `pytesseract` output into a list and then split it but I can't get it to work.

The part of the code that is not working:

```
mylist = [] 
mylist = [pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))] 
print(mylist) 
list2 = mylist.split() 
print(list2)
```

And the output I get is:

```
['33 44 55\n\x0c'] list2 = mylist.split( ) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the list? It is already split. `list` has no `split()` only `string` objects have `split()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want to use the string's (`str`) `split` function on a `list` object.

Lets interpret step-by-step

```py
mylist = []
```

You don't need to declare `mylist` as an empty `list`, since

```py
mylist = [pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))]
```

you have already declared. But if you want to use the `split`, then you need to declare `mylist` without brackets.

```py
mylist = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
```

Now if you check `mylist` type

```
print(type(mylist))
```

The result should be:

```py
<class 'str'>
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) you need to give an input parameter. For instance:

```py
list2 = mylist.split("\n") 
print(list2)
```

Split `mylist` based on `"\n"` character. Therefore the correct implementation will be:

```py
mylist = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
print(mylist) 
list2 = mylist.split() 
print(list2)
```